# SwiftUI watchOS How to display array content as subviews in a single View?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, watchos

I'm doing an Apple Watch app, using SwiftUI. The idea is to display different activity content in a single watch ContentView using four individual *subviews* within the ContentView Body View. I don't want to use a List to display the activity content, but rather multiple custom views within the ContentView.

I would like each individual *subview* to display unique content from my model.

My model is called `QuadActivity` and has the following content:

```
struct QuadActivity: Identifiable {

  let id = UUID()
  var activityImage: Image
  var activityTitle: String
}
```

I currently have created an extension to `QuadActivity` as follows, to hold some hardcoded test data:

```
extension QuadActivity {
  
  static func all() -> [QuadActivity] {
    
     return [
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage1, activityTitle: "activity1"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage2, activityTitle: "activity2"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage3, activityTitle: "activity3"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage4, activityTitle: "activity4")]
  }
}
```

My `ContentView.swift` Body view is made up of a VStack with 2 HStacks embedded. Each HStack contains 2 of my *subviews* with miscellaneous spacers and padding modifiers. Each of the *subviews* should display the content of one of the array elements from an instance property:

```
 var activityArrayEntry = QuadActivity.all()
```

Thus HStack 1 should display `activityImage1` and `activity1` and `activityImage2` and `activity2`. The other HStack should display the array elements for items 3 and 4.

I can't figure out how to access each of the `activityArrayEntry` array elements and display each one in one of the *subviews*.

I was thinking I could use a:

```
ForEach(activityArrayEntry) { activity in
  VStack and embedded HStack code here}
```

and display the *subview* content by looping through the ForEach above.

However, since all my VStack and HStack and *subview* code is within the ForEach loop, the same array element activity content would be displayed for all *subviews* because the loop encompasses all the view information for a single pass of the loop. I want each *subview* to display one of the unique array element's content.

If I move the ForEach within the ZStack and HStack code for each HStack *subview* display section, it will loop through the array entries, but the loop won't encompass all the *subviews* code and I won't get all the *subviews* to display only the activity array content from 1 array element.

Maybe using a `ForEach` loop is not the way. Is there another way to access the individual array elements from my instance variable such that each unique array element is used only in 1 of the *subviews*?

Again, how do I get the overall `ContentView.swift` to display the four *subviews* within the ZStack and HStack structure so that each *subview* displays the activity content of only 1 of the array elements.

Here is my `ContentView` so far. Note a number of commented lines that I will eventually comeback to in order to use an Observed Object model approach from a @Published Observable Object of my model. This will eventually be (maybe) the approach instead of the function all() from my model that I'm using now with hardcoded data to test the data flow in my app... thus the original question/issue.

**Note**

Call to `QuadView()` is just a call to an extracted subview where I define the display of the subview (simple Image and Text):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
//    @ObservedObject var quadViewVM = QuadViewVM()
    var activityArrayEntry = QuadActivity.all()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                Divider()
                    .frame(height: 175.0)
                
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
            
            ForEach(activityArrayEntry) { activity in

            VStack {
                
                
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    QuadView(activityTitle: "\(activity.activityTitle)", activityImage: activity.activityImage)
                    
                        //                        NavigationLink(destination: QuadDetail(content: , newActivity: false)) {
                        //
                        //                        }
                        .frame(width: 85.0, height: 100.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    QuadView(activityTitle: "\(activity.activityTitle)", activityImage: activity.activityImage)
                    
                        //                        NavigationLink(destination: QuadDetail()) {
                        //
                        //                        }
                        
                        .frame(width: 85.0, height: 100.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)
                .padding(.bottom, -10.0)
                
                Divider()
                
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    QuadView(activityTitle: "\(activity.activityTitle)", activityImage: activity.activityImage)
                    
                        //                        NavigationLink(destination: QuadDetail()) {
                        //
                        //                        }
                        
                        .frame(width: 85.0, height: 100.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    QuadView(activityTitle: "\(activity.activityTitle)", activityImage: activity.activityImage)
                    
                        //                        NavigationLink(destination: QuadDetail()) {
                        //
                        //                        }
                        .frame(width: 85.0, height: 100.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
                    
                .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing], 15.0)
                .padding(.top, -10.0)
                    
                    
                .padding(.top, 30.0)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of static `QuadActivity.all()` you can store your data in the `ViewModel`:

```
class QuadViewVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var quadActivities: [QuadActivity] = [
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage1, activityTitle: "activity1"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage2, activityTitle: "activity2"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage3, activityTitle: "activity3"),
        QuadActivity(activityImage: activityImage4, activityTitle: "activity4"),
    ]
}
```

In your `ContentView` you can create a grid by using two `ForEach` loops (as it's a 2D grid):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var quadViewVM = QuadViewVM()
    let columnCount = 2
    var rowCount: Int {
        quadViewVM.quadActivities.count / columnCount
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Horizontal divider
            VStack {
                Divider()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
            // Vertical divider
            HStack {
                Divider()
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)

            activityGrid
        }
    }

    var activityGrid: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.rowCount) { row in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0 ..< self.columnCount) { column in
                        self.quadView(row: row, column: column)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func quadView(row: Int, column: Int) -> some View {
        let activity = quadViewVM.quadActivities[row * columnCount + column]
        return QuadView(activity: activity)
            .frame(width: 85.0, height: 100.0)
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

The `QuadView` is extracted to another function to make it more readable and easier to apply view modifiers.

I'd also recommend passing the whole `QuadActivity` variable to the `QuadView` (instead of its single components) - specifically when you need them all:

```
struct QuadView: View {
    let activity: QuadActivity

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I see by using the nested ForEach loops with row and column paraders, your able to target specific array Lee lime I wanted to do. I’ll try this approach and report back.

Comment: I used this approach and, with a little .padding() manipulation, this worked. I was also able to move forward and add a NavigationLink to take me to my DetailView. Thank you. Now I'm hoping Apple will announce an easier way to do grids/collection views at WWDC20.

Comment: @andyzoom01 FYI, in SwiftUI 2 you can use native *Grids*, see [SwiftUI Lazy Grid Tutorial](https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-lazy-grid-tutorial)